# How to parse more than one xml files

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml, php-parser

I need to implement a PHP file to read x files from a directory and every time update a table in my db. With the update no problem but, i'm not the best with xml in php. So, this is the xml file:

```
<SeasonStatistics competition_name="Italian Serie A" season_name="Season 2015/2016" season_id="2015" competition_id="21">
 <Team name="Roma" id="121"><Stat name="Total Shots">102</Stat>
  <Stat name="Possession Percentage">64</Stat><Stat name="Total Fouls Won">93</Stat>
  <Stat name="Unsuccessful Dribbles">60</Stat>
  <Stat name="PutThrough/Blocked Distribution">125</Stat>
  <Stat name="Goals">17</Stat>
  <Stat name="Headed Goals">2</Stat>
  <Stat name="Unsuccessful lay-offs">5</Stat>
  <Stat name="Total Passes">3868</Stat><Stat name="Crossing Accuracy">21.55</Stat>
  <Stat name="Throw Ins to Opposition Player">12</Stat>
  <Stat name="Total Unsuccessful Passes ( Excl Crosses & Corners )">543</Stat>
  <Stat name="Shots On Conceded Inside Box">21</Stat>
  <Stat name="Throw Ins to Own Player">127</Stat>
  <Stat name="Shots On Target ( inc goals )">50</Stat>
  <Stat name="Clean Sheets">1</Stat>
  <Player position="Defender" player_id="61021" shirtNumber="5" known_name="Leandro Castán" last_name="Castan da Silva" first_name="Leandro">
   <Stat name="Time Played">90</Stat>
   <Stat name="Successful Launches">1</Stat>
   <Stat name="Open Play Passes">42</Stat>
   <Stat name="Backward Passes">1</Stat>
   </Player>
  </Team>
 </SeasonStatistics>
```

So, I have x files in my directory and i need to read all. When i'm reading a file i want:

> -$array($teamname -----> $position ->$statval)
>   -$array2($playerstat ----> $position ----->$statval)

How can I do this? And when the first xml's file will finish how I can parse the next?

Thx to all
Matteo

Comment: Yes, burlt how i can parse a file and transform into 2 array?

Answer (score 0):

Hint for parsing xml:

```
$content = '<xml>....</xml>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($content);
```

Comment: nope. I need to read X FILES (i don't know the content, everytime content change), make an array and after update table in my db.